# Parameter type must not include a type variable or wildcard

Tags: android, retrofit2

in my android app I use Retrofit 2:

```
public enum OperationType {
    @SerializedName("payment")
    PAYMENT,
    @SerializedName("payout")
    PAYOUT,
    @SerializedName("transfer")
    TRANSFER
}




fun getOperationsList(typeList: List<OperationType>, callback: Callback<List<Operation>>) {
        val call = myRestClient.getOperationsList(typeList)
        executeRequest(call, callback)
}


@GET("/operations")
fun getOperationsList(@Query("type") typeList: List<OperationType>): Call<List<Operation>>
```

but I get runtime error in this line:

```
val call = myRestClient.getOperationsList(typeList)
```

error:

```
Shutting down VM
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: md.qsystems.android.tango.debug, PID: 22714
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter type must not include a type variable or wildcard: java.util.List<? extends OperationType> (parameter #1)
     for method TangoRestClient.getOperationsList
    at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:52)
    at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:42)
    at retrofit2.Utils.parameterError(Utils.java:61)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.validateResolvableType(RequestFactory.java:764)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(RequestFactory.java:401)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameter(RequestFactory.java:306)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.build(RequestFactory.java:193)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory.parseAnnotations(RequestFactory.java:67)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:26)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:149)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
    at $Proxy1.getOperationsList(Unknown Source)
    at mTransportService.getOperationsList(TransportService.kt:160)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> You can add `@JvmSuppressWildcards` either inside the angle brackets before the String type, or before the List.
> Both should work and remove the wildcard.

Workaround taken from [this issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2457).

Comment: IDE was showing `Unresolved reference` error until I added **s** at the end, so use `@JvmSuppressWildcards`